is famous Hinduism lecturer Dushyanth Sridhar correct when he says Amruta does not confer immortality?
In this Tamil lecture,
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=voAlqEMrEhM&t=620s

அமிர்தம் உண்டால் அமரத்துவம் கிடைப்பது உண்மையா?

entitled by u-tube as

Is it true that if you get nectar, you will get immortality?

He says all it does is to preserve youthfulness - but cannot ward off death.  According to the belief-system of the Srivaishnavite sect he belongs to - only Vishnu can be immortal, not even Brahma.
But Bhagavata Purana says that Devas and even Rahu obtained immortality from Amruta:
https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-bhagavata-purana/d/doc1128823.html




When the gods and demons (sons of Diti) were sitting with their faces to the east in that hall fragrant with incense, decorated with wreaths of flowers and illuminated with lamps, there entered, with the jar of nectar in hands, she (Mohinī) with beautiful, round, symmetrical thighs, of gait slow dus (to the weight of) her bulky hips covered with brilliant silk raiment, eyes swimming as if through inebriation, of pitcher-like big breasts, warbling (as it were) with the jingling of her gold anklets, Oh King.






Ogling Her, the veritable supreme Deity, as a compeer to goddess Śrī[3] (or Lakṣmī in beauty), with a winning countenance, having beautiful ears adorned with gold ear-rings, shapely nose and charming cheeks, the gods and demons were completely enchanted by her glances accompanied with captivating smiles while her brassiere (the cloth cover of her breasts) slipped (exposing her breasts).




Considering that it is unfair to offer nectar to demons who like serpents are wicked by nature, Lord Viṣṇu did not distribute it to Asuras.




Arranging them both in separate rows, the Lord of the world made them sit in their respective rows.




Taking the Jar of nectar and beguiling the demons by charming movements of brows. bashful smiles, play with garment and ornaments, sweet flattering words, he made gods who were sitting at a distance, to drink the nectar which prevents old age and death.




Oh King! The Asuras abided by the pledge given by them. Out of covetous lust for her and feeling it below their dignity to quarrel with a lady, they kept quiet.




They cherished unbounded attachment and lustful longing for her and were too nervous to affect it adversely. Being restrained by the high reverence shown to them by her (“Let the niggardly gods drink first. Sensible people like you should wait a bit”) they uttered nothing unpleasant.




Disguising himself in the garb of celestials, Rāhu entered (stealthily) in the row of gods (between the sun and the moon) and drank the nectar but was indicated (exposed with gestures) by the sun and the moon (who feared him as more powerful than they).




Just while he (Rāhu) was drinking, Hari (swiftly) severed his head with his discus of razor-like sharpness so his headless trunk to which nectar did not touch, fell down dead.




His head (however) attained immortality upon which the Birthless Lord conferred planet-hood But cherishing (this old) enmity, he assails the sun and the moon on the new-moon-day and the full-moon-day (respectively whenever he gets an opportunity).



Related: hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/58940/34973 He's correct as that immortality is until the end of a Kalpa. It isn't the same as the Amrita described in the Upanishad or Tantra which bestows the realization of the self

lasting as long as the Sun and the Moon is effectively immortality @harihara

We'll need to understand that Dushyant Sridhar is extremely learned in Sanatana Dharma. So he must have said something keeping the overall scriptural essence in mind and not cherry picking on one or a few verses like most of us do. So I'll give his statement the benefit of doubt rather than concluding it to be incorrect.

His argument is based on "even Brahma is not immortal" based on the itihasapuranic belly-lotus origin story of Brahma.  But Brahma goes back to Rig Veda where he is Brahman.  @harihara

The same appears in different forms at different times. So the Rg Vedic quote and the incident from the Bhagavata Purana are both equally true.
